# Show that the cross product a x b is skew symmetric.

Tags: vectors, cross-product, skew-symmetric-matrices

Given two vectors a, b ∈ R3: a x b (cross product). Show that the cross product is skew symmetric.
If AT = −A which means A is skew symmetric then prove that (A+B)
is also skew symmetric.
I managed to prove it like this: (A+B)T
= AT+BT =(−A+−B)=−(A+B)
Therefore (A+B)T
=−(A+B)
which is skew symmetric.

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the cross-product is skew-symmetric ($a\times b=-b\times a$) or that skew-symmetric matrices ($A^\top=-A$) are stable under addition?

Comment: Does AT etc. stand for $A^T$? In your proof that $A+B$ is skew symmetric you seem to use that $B$ is also skew symmetric, but you do not mention that as a condition. -- For the first part, waht is your definition of the cross product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$ and $b=(b_{1},b_{2},b_{3})$ then the cross product $a\times b$ is given by:
$$a\times b = \mbox{det}\begin{bmatrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\ b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} \end{bmatrix} $$
Thus, if you interchange $a$ and $b$ you interchange the second and third rows of the above matrix, which culminates in a change of sign. This proves the cross product is skew-symmetric. You can explicitly calculate it, if you prefer.